# Memcached Dynamic Key Generation from Array of n-many Integers

Tags: php, caching, hash, key, memcached

Ive been reading a lot about different techniques for storing large keys with Memcached in PHP. There seems to be a lot of chatter about hashing parameters or strings (like queries) to form a key, and bits of wisdom to suggest difficulties with scale, collisions, and CPU use. Most of the voices against using a hash, even md5, to form a Memcached key dont offer a solution for a problem like the following:

Lets say a given PHP application has a caching strategy where all domain classes' functions use a short descriptive prefix string (like "usr_profile_") with function arguments concatenated. So a function like:

```
public function getUserProfile($user_id)
{
   // doin the needful ;)
}
```

Would dynamically create a key like:

```
$key = "usr_profile_{$user_id}";
```

For a function that receives an array as an argument, such as an array of user IDs, or blog post IDs, etc, what is the best way to create the cache key with scalability in mind?

The above methodology may not work when the array contains a large number of elements. Fewer than 50 5-digit integers would result in a cache key too big for memcache.

What if the array argument contained large numbers of IDs/integers, such as 200 user IDs where each ID is 6 digits long? Serializing or imploding this array could easily create a key too large, and using a hash on any string representation of the array [such as: md5(implode('-',$user_ids_array)); ] could make it difficult to scale horizontally, as well as consume a fair amount of CPU time.

Ive thought of a few solutions to this problem, such as refactoring code or caching the elements within the array individually, but am curious as to what the community thinks. Im hesitant to explore using any hashing algorithm at all for storing large cache keys.